# Using Dreamhost GIT repository in OSX Git tower app

Tags: macos, git, dreamhost, git-tower

I just follow these rules in order to create my first git repository on my Dreamhost account. It create a git folder in my user home root.

Now, I don't know how to clone this repository locally using osx Tower app.

Did someone have already did it and could help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tower Git has document on cloning repository - http://www.git-tower.com/files/applicationHelp/pgs/GettingStarted_AddFirstRepo.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.